# Easiest way to render html and getting its source using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using [online oracle apex facility](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4500:1000:682831272909901). I want to get the html source of any page I want; say www.google.com. I have tried:

```
select httpuritype('http://www.google.com').getclob() google from dual
```

This code is giving me ORA-29273 ACL error.

Comment: this sounds like a firewall/credential issue.  Try accessing a local URL (within your intranet) as you did above and see if it works. (keep in mind, the server where oracle resides is probably locked down!)

Comment: its still giving me  ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1819 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Comment: @lconfused :Please refere this link ,might help you in creating ACL http://ginodalfonso.blogspot.in/2012/06/ora-29273-http-request-failed.html

Comment: @GauravSoni I think the url you mentioned will need an instance working on local machine to perform it, i will try it as well. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother on apex.oracle.com. The database, 11g, has network ACLs, and you need to be granted priviliges to access an ip/url/range. No use trying it on there, you don't have the necessary priviliges to perform that action.